# Why my files get redownloaded on postback in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

Hi I am using following handler to provide file download on my asp.net web app :

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (SFTDBEntities db = new SFTDBEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                string Id = context.Request.QueryString["Id"];
                Guid Id_LogServerLogFilesData = Guid.Parse(Id);
                LogServerLogFile logServerLogFile = new LogServerLogFile();
                logServerLogFile = db.LogServerLogFiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id_LogServerLogFilesData);
                byte[] data = logServerLogFile.LogServerLogFilesData.TFFileData.ToArray();
                context.Response.Buffer = false;
                context.Response.ContentType = logServerLogFile.TFFileMimeType;
                int len = data.Length, bytes;
                context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", len.ToString());
                context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + logServerLogFile.TFFileName);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                Stream outStream = context.Response.OutputStream;
                using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    while (len > 0 && (bytes =
                        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                        len -= bytes;
                    }
                }
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.End();
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

When I click on a hyperlink in my gridview to download a file :

```
                     <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btn" runat="server" Text="download" PostBackUrl='<%#Eval("DownloadPath") %>' Visible='<%#Eval("TFIsDownloadable") %>' Style="text-decoration: none"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

the file downloads successfully 1

BUT the issue is that after the file is downloaded if I perform a postback (Page the grid or click on search button)  the files is being downloaded again automaticaly!

any helps would be appreciated .

Comment: why you are using LinkButton? It would be easier to use usual HyperLink with Url that will have link to your handler and needed parameters. in that case it will behave like usual link without any submits.

Comment: how and where  you are calling handler which is downloading the file?

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Because I want to set the visibility of download button using Eval

Comment: @Pawan I have set the PostBackUrl='<%#Eval("DownloadPath") %>' of the linkbutton and I think that the handler would be called when user clicks that link

Comment: If your handler is separate IHttpHandler file, then you don't need to do it as PostBack. HyperLink also can be hidden with Visible property

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov I am using an IHttpHandler , I tried <a href='<%#Eval("DownloadPath") %>' Visible="<%#Eval("TFIsDownloadable") %>">download</a> the file downloads but the Visible attribiute does not work

Comment: Yes, because you didn't specified runat='server'. Or you can use HyperLink and NavigateUrl property that will do the same as `a` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Fiddler or a similar tool to inspect your requests.

had a similar issue which was caused by request parameters persisting across to subsequent postbacks. (i.e. theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value did not change).